# Attribute img not allowed on element img at this point

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I've got a problem.
I started coding yesterday and I got an error when I wanted to verify my website on W3Validator:

> Error: Attribute img not allowed on element img at this point.

Here is the code which causes the problem:

```
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/Koeen_Yt?lang=fr"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" img style="vertical-align:middle" width="100" height="85" > Follow moi grow ! </a></li>
```

Comment: you added img two times and close img tag like this <img src="image.jpg" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another `img` inside the image tag...

this is the corrected code...

```
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/Koeen_Yt?lang=fr"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="vertical-align:middle" width="100" height="85" > Follow moi grow ! </a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks , sorry that was the first time I code , i'm on training actually ^^

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if it is the right one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `img` you have *inside* your `<img ...>` tag is an attribute:

```
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/Koeen_Yt?lang=fr"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" img style="vertical-align:middle" width="100" height="85" > Follow moi grow ! </a></li>
<!-- This one >>------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^                                       -->
```

[`img` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) don't have an `img` attribute. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a boolean attribute. But since `img` is not a boolean attribute, it causes the error. Validator expects an assignment to the attribute. Custom attributes without assignments are not allowed except boolean. If you need to add attributes, there are following ways:

- use `img=""`
- use data-img=""

Refer: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute

https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#elements-attributes

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element

Answer (score 0):

Remove img attribute from img tag, it is not a attribute of image,

Use this

```html
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/Koeen_Yt?lang=fr"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="vertical-align:middle" width="100" height="85" > Follow moi grow ! </a></li>
```